# Manual captcha solving imacros

Tags: captcha, imacros

I'm trying to make a macro which given an URL its asks me for the captcha and re-submits a listing, so far this is what I have:

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=about:newtab
URL GOTO=http://www.revolico.com/modificar-anuncio.html?key=WyqAGDMyFyoH15527264
WAIT SECONDS=6
URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,20000)
PROMPT "Enter captcha" !VAR1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:insertad ATTR=ID:recaptcha_response_field CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:insertad ATTR=NAME:send_form
```

I don't want to scroll all the way down to see the captcha but to show the image in the prompt, can anyone help me?

This is a classified ads website and you can use the given url to test.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add tags to images of post scroll right in the picture
like this:
TAG POS = 1 TYPE = a ATTR = DIV ID: adcopy-puzzle-image

change the id of the image fits the image on the website that may help